# Need to check for nil before allocating object

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title says: is it necessary or is it good practice to check if an object is nil before allocating and initializing it, like so?

```
if (!_menuFetcher) {
    _menuFetcher = [[MenuFetcher alloc] init];
    _menuFetcher.delegate = self;

}
```

I presume this is called lazy loading right?

Comment: It is better to check wether the object is nil before accessing it. Use property accessors that will manage memory for you.

Comment: So instead of using the instance variable _iVar, I should use self.iVar instead? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading is deferring the creation of an object until you need it. UIViewController does that with its view -- creating a view hierarchy takes a good deal of time and memory, so it isn't done until the view is accessed. You might implement lazy loading using a conditional statement like the one you've shown. Ideally, you'd put that in the accessor for a property and use the property everywhere so you don't have conditionals all over the place.

It's not bad practice to check whether an object exists, but using properties lets you limit the number of places where you need to do so, which simplifies the rest of your code.

It's not necessary to always check whether something exists before allocating -- most of the time you should already know. For example, in your `-init` method you know that nothing has been allocated yet, and you can create whatever objects your new object will need.

Comment: Thank you. So would I need to create the lazy load getters for all my variables? and then use  self.iVar instead of _iVar?

Comment: No, most of the time you should simply set your ivars if you need them to be set. Using properties instead of ivars is often a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this basically prevents re-initialising something that was already initialised. You should always do this, unless you are 100% sure that you are not re-initialising. However, this is not called Lazy Loading - that something different.

Lazy loading is used, for example, when loading images in a table view. Instead of loading all of the images that are in the table view, you only load these ones that are visible on screen. This approach is better for loading times, performance and memory.

Comment: This is lazy loading and it may well be applied to images in tables too. It basically means that an object is loaded when it is accessed though an accessor for the first time. Quite suitable for resouce consuming images in table view cells.

Comment: Well, yes you're right. But I think that everybody will think of tables loading images and similar when you say lazy loading :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do something like this in a getter method.

Say you have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MenuFetcher *menuFetcher;
```

That you use in a view controller say, then you can implement a getter for the property as so:

```
- (MenuFetcher *)menuFetcher 
{
    if (!_menuFetcher) {
        _menuFetcher = [[MenuFetcher alloc] init];
        _menuFetcher.delegate = self;
    }
    return _menuFetcher;
}
```

You're correct that this is a form of lazy initialisation (rather than loading) - the memory is not allocated nor the instance initialised until the point it is required.  Also, you don't need to have a centralised initialisation routine, nor do you need to worry about the object being set up yet - if it doesn't exist it gets created - if you blow it away by setting it back to nil, the next time something wants an instance of that type, it gets created again. So it is somewhat elegant and efficient in that regard.

So, in effect, the first time you try to read the property by calling `self.menuFetcher`, if it hasn't been setup yet, your getter will notice it is nil and create and initialise it for you.  Once set, the property is no longer nil, so the getter just returns the object as held.

Use lazy initialisation if that is appropriate for what you are writing. The only thing to really watch out for is getters that do other things beyond the lazy initialisation - getters that have 'side effects' can be a pain if things go wrong. Keep them simple and focused.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you just need to instanciate a new object then there is no need to check for nil.

There is no need to check for nil before allocating an object. Not at all.

However, this is some quite good and widely spread pattern where you check for nil before acutally using the object. If the reference is nil then you create it 'on the fly'. You have to see it in the context of the following code (either here or in the caller). There _menuFetcher will be used in some way. (most probabyl at least.) 
Or this is in a method that may be called multiple times like `viewWillAppear` in a view controller. You may have good reasons not to instanciate and initilize the object earlier and wnat to instanicate it only once. On the next call of that very method you would simply reuse the object that was created earlier.

(I meant to write this in a comment first, not an answer. But it became to long for a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading means 'loading on demand', you perform operation only when it is really needed, it something like:

```
- (MenuFetcher *)instance{
    if (_menuFetcher == nil){
        _menuFetcher = [[MenuFetcher alloc] init];
    }
    return _menuFetcher;
}
```

Comment: Nearly :-) You may want to return _menuFetcher or check and assign it to _ivar.

Comment: Haha, some headache after a long time of arguing with the client :S